# Why facebook does not let me create more applications?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have in my account several pages of several clients on Facebook, and I need, in 14 of these pages create 5 tabs with iframes for each one.

For this I have seen that there are two methods, one requires having 2000 fans. This I discard. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs)

The other needs to create an application for each tab (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs)

Considering this I need to create 70 app id for 70 tabs.

I have created and configured 8 app id and it does not let me create more, when I try to create a new app id I get the following message:

Oops
"Something went wrong, we're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can."

**Do you know if it is any limitation?**

I've been searching a lot on the internet without success.

After that:

I have created about 14 more applications but now from my personal developer account and it has blocked me again with the same message.

Comment: Have you contacted Facebook about this?

Comment: What “two methods” are you talking about here?

Comment: I have not found a way to contact facebook

Comment: there is no limit, look like you just have to wait because "they are working on getting it fixed".

Comment: I have created about 14 more applications but now from my personal developer account and it has blocked me again with the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was a matter of time. After creating between 11 and 14 apps, I was not allowed to create more.

I had to wait between 24 and 48 hours to create another 10 or 14.

So I did several times until I finished.